# Make Completion Progress Script

Tags: compiling, make, c, dependencies

Any time I'm executing a build process that takes several hours, I inevitably stare at my terminal and wonder, "how much longer?"  Sometimes, I manually pick up on some pathname echoed to the terminal and then go into the maze of makefiles to determine where in the build process I am.  This is obviously an imperfect, tedious process, so I was wondering, does any program out there do this automatically?  I can imagine a script that goes through the make dependencies and constructs a dependency tree, and then, using some heuristic, estimates how much of the tree has been "completed" or "built."

Has anyone ever heard of something like this?

Comment: Jenkins does an estimate based on the previous build time

Answer (score 1):

[CMake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) builds makefiles for you which, among other, feature a progress indicator.